# I Can't Set The Part's Color, Why?

Tags: lua, roblox

The Problem Is That I Can't Color A Part,
And I Don't Know Why.

I Tried

```
local hue = (tonumber(BlockClass.Size) or 1) / 100 -- BlockClass.Size Is A Number, But Incase It's Not, It Sets To 1.
-- BlockClass.Size Is Usually 2, 4, 8 And So On.
block.Color = Color3.fromHSV(hue, 1, 1) -- Hue (The Color), Saturation (The Amount Of Color), Value (The Brightness)
```

And I Expected It To Set The Color Accordingly.

What Actually Happened Is Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a part color via the properties window, you just need to select the part, open up the properties window then change the color (at the very top), you don't need scripts to set a part color. I'd request that you add more details explaining your problem